# Where are RHEL9 bugs reported in 2023?

Tags: rhel, bugs

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 is no longer listed as a product under bugzilla at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?classification=Red%20Hat

There are no onward links indicating the issuer tracker has moved, or where it has moved to.

Google comes up with nothing.

Anyone know where bugs are reported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 in September 2023?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RHEL moved from bugzilla to Jira see the [RHEL project](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RHEL) at [issues.redhat.com](https://issues.redhat.com). I didn't find an official announcement, only [this thread](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/U7TZRWXVUGBCHS6EBJIBSFAVPFUHHV7J/) on Fedora Devel mailing list announcing the move in 2022.

CentOS Wiki now also points to Red Hat Jira for [reporting bugs](https://wiki.centos.org/ReportBugs) against CentOS Stream 8 to 10.

Edit: An update about the migration was posted on [Fedora Devel](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/VT5G3V3YB63R2ASEDSUMO333R6Q5WJ4M/) mailing list with more details about reporting new bug reports for RHEL/CentOS and migrating existing reports to Jira:

> All new issues found or desired in RHEL (Or CentOS Stream) need to be filed on issues.redhat.com.  It's no longer possible to create new BZs for current RHEL (7 through 9) releases.  Over the next few weeks, most RHEL BZs will be migrated to tickets in the RHEL project on issues.redhat.com. The BZs that are migrated will be closed with resolution MIGRATED and a pointer to the Jira issue included in the external links section of each
> respective BZ.

Comment: For an official reference related to this move, see the entries for RHEL 5 and lower in BZ: they all say “For Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 and above, please visit Red Hat JIRA https://issues.redhat.com/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa?pid=12332745 to report new issues.”

Comment: Bugzilla still work: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/buglist.cgi?chfield=%5BBug%20creation%5D&chfieldfrom=-7d

Comment: @RomeoNinov Bugzilla still works, yes, but if you follow the documented links for RHEL 9 bugs you end up with an error message and no indication of where to go next. You also won’t find the appropriate product to file a RHEL issue for RHEL 6 or later (that’s what the question is about).

Comment: @StephenKitt, try again: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/buglist.cgi?bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&classification=Red%20Hat&columnlist=product%2Ccomponent%2Cassigned_to%2Cstatus%2Csummary%2Clast_change_time%2Cseverity%2Cpriority&order=status%2C%20priority%2C%20assigned_to%2C%20id%2C%20&product=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%209&query_format=advanced   RHEL 9, last activity September 2023

Comment: @RomeoNinov try creating a bug against RHEL 9.

Comment: @StephenKitt, you should start with this because it is relevant

Comment: @RomeoNinov the whole question is about reporting bugs, not about accessing old ones. (In any case all the old ones have been migrated to Jira too. If you look at the BZ issues with recent activity, you’ll see that you can’t see that activity because it’s internal book-keeping.)